# Mongoengine database query inside models: should I avoid this? How to do it in a different way?

Tags: flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have this model structure:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    artist = db.StringField()

class Collection(db.Model):
    # a collection delivers a list of items.
    name = db.StringField()

class ListCollection(Collection):
    # the items are static
    items = db.ListField(Item)

class OtherCollection(Collection):
    # the items are queried dynamically, like a dynamic playlist for example
    artist = db.StringField()
    @property
    def items(self):   
        return Item.objects(artist=artist).all()
```

Now, `OtherCollection` messes up the model -> view separation, I think. `OtherCollection` has a name, maybe owner and so on (therefore, it is a "model" I think), but `items` is the result of a database query, at least in the `OtherCollection` subclass. And a query can be thought of as a "view", not a model.

My question is: how can this be modelled differently?

Comment: What are `images` and `OtherModel`?

Comment: @dirn, sorry, my fault. Should have been "item" and "Collection", I edited the question.